# An annoying optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

At first I thought the following problem looked simple, but I've had serious problems pinning it down:

Suppose that $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i$ is fixed. Then find the minimum value of
$$\sum_{i=1}^k (1 - x_i)^k$$
in the range $0 \leq x_1, \dots, x_k \leq 1$.

A first conjecture is that it should be minimised when $x_1 = \dots = x_k$. This turns out to be false when the product is small, but I still suspect it's true when the product is reasonably large, say at least $1/2^k$. Does anyone see a simple or reasonable way to analyze this? You can get somewhere with Lagrange multipliers, but it doesn't seem to be enough. I also thought there might be an elementary argument I'm missing.

Perhaps I should flesh this out a little more. Using Lagrange multipliers, one can show that $x_i(1-x_i)^{k-1}$ is the same for each $i$. Since the function $x(1-x)^{k-1}$ has a unique maximum (at $x = 1/k$), this shows that the $x_i$ take at most $2$ values. But I've had trouble reducing the problem any further, partly because, as I said, there are cases where the minimum is not in the expected place.

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect it to be at $x_1 = \cdots = x_k$ whenever $k$ is high enough or the product is high enough.  Can you come up with a simple curvature argument to find the threshold?

Comment: BTW, where does this problem come from?

Comment: Writing $x$ as $e^t$, the function $y(t) = (1-e^t)^k$ is convex/concave when $x$ is greater/less than $\frac1k$. From this, you can deduce the minimal configuration has at most one $x_i < \frac1k$ and all $x_i \ge \frac1k$ equals to each other. Assume $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_k$, the minimal configuration either has the form (1) $\frac1k \le x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_k$ or (2) $x_1 < \frac1k \le x_2 = \cdots = x_k $. It just turns out when $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i < \frac{1}{k^k}$, the second forms wins. I'll leave the (tedious) details to you :-p

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Comment: Use the power mean inequality